# Mismatching target dimension in Keras LSTM

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I have built this network for text classification:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_dim, 150, input_length=max_length)) 
model.add(LSTM(150, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I fit the model:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=5, batch_size=128)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_9 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (12481, 3)
```

I suppose because `y_train` and `y_val` are `one-hot` encoded, with shape:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       .............])
```

but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Change this `model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))` to `model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))`

Answer (score 3):

With a single output unit `model.add(Dense(**1**, activation='softmax'))`, Keras is expecting a binary outcome, and so the 'softmax' activation function and the 'categorical_crossentropy' loss are not appropriate.

If your output is binary, use: `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))` and `model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy'`.

If your outcome is not binary, then the number of output units needs to be adjusted to match the number of output categories.